# I can't fix [TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object]

Tags: python-3.x

I have been looking other posts but I couldn't find the answer for my problem.

```py
class Libro():
    def __init__(self):
        self.autor = ""
    def setAutor (self, new_autor):
        regex = "[^\d\s]+( [^\d\s]+)*"
        if re.fullmatch (regex, new_autor):
            self.autor = new_autor
        else:
            print("\n\n ****** ERROR ******")
            self.autor = ""
libro  = Libro()

class Comic(Libro):
    def __init__(self):
        Libro.__init__(self)
        libro.setAutor(self)
comic = Comic()
```

That is the error that I have and I don't know how I can fix

```
  In <module>
     comic = Comic()

  In __init__
     libro.setAutor(self)

  In setAutor 
     if re.fullmatch (regex, new_autor):

  In fullmatch
     "return _compile(pattern, flags).fullmatch(string)"

  TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: `libro.setAutor(self)` what are you doing here? setAuthor uses regex to match against string and you are passing an object of type Comic to it.

Comment: Hi @SMA. My program is a library that allows you to write titles of books and comic and associate authors, publishers ... etc.
I want to create a rule that does not allow you to write numbers when you are writing authors.
Did I explain well? 
I want to make it clear that I am a beginner in python

Comment: So you should pass a string to `setAuthor` method that you would want to assign author as, instead of instance of `Comic`

Comment: Could you make an example? I don't know how can I do it.

Comment: libro.setAuthor("Lady Gaga");

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance! But, I want that the string be applied for all keyboard inputs

Comment: Thanks @SMA. I am making stupid things.... It was so evident.